# Animation not working on mobile

Tags: angular

I have the following animation defined:

```
trigger('animateX', [
        transition('void => *', [
            style({
                '-ms-transform': 'translateY(-100%)',
                '-webkit-transform': 'translateY(-100%)',
                'transform': 'translateY(-100%)'
            }),
            animate('1000ms ease-in')
        ]),
        transition('* => void', [
            animate('1000ms ease-in', style({
                '-ms-transform': 'translateY(100%)',
                '-webkit-transform': 'translateY(100%)',
                'transform': 'translateY(100%)'
            }))
        ])
    ]),
```

The animation works fine on desktop but it is not animating on iPhone 6 in Chrome or safari. Any idea why it´s not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular 2 uses the latest Webanimation API. It is not yet supported on Safari.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=web-animation

There is a polyfill available, but from what I have seen, it makes the app less responsive.

https://github.com/web-animations/web-animations-js

Comment: I guess it´s also not supported in Chrome on iOS?

Comment: Correct, it uses Safari's rendering engine.

Comment: No longer needed for Angular 6 (unless you're using AnimationBuilder)